# Using a custom webpack loader in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-loader

I am using Nuxt.js, and I want to tell Webpack to use a specific loader ([`raw-loader`](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/raw-loader)) for a specific file extension (`.pug`). According to the documentation, I should add custom webpack rules using `build.extend`, i.e. something like this:

```js
build: {
  // Extend webpack config
  extend(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.pug$/,
      use: "raw-loader",
    })
  },
}
```

However, this will not work if the file format is already matched by a built-in rule (as is the case with .pug). My rule will be overridden by the built-in rule.

What is the recommended way to replace *a specific* webpack rule? I currently resorted to awkwardly loop through all existing rules to overwrite those interfering with my rule, like this:

```js
build: {
  // Extend webpack config
  extend(config) {
      config.module.rules = config.module.rules
        .map(x => {
          if (x.test.source.includes(".pug")) {
            return {
              test: /\.pug$/,
              use: "raw-loader",
            }
          } else {
            return x
          }
        })
  },
}
```